# iPhone NSTimer running single method

Tags: ios, nstimer

I'm new to programming for the iPhone and i'm having a problem with this function

```
-(IBAction)changeX {
    [self timere:field1];
    [self timere:field2];
}
```

this is a button to move an uitextfield object across the screen. The problem is i want to run this method on the first field , complete it then go on to the second. The timere function uses  NSTimer to continously move the object until it reaches a certain point at which it terminates. I have two other functions shown below. The actual program im making is much longer but the objective is the same and that code is too long. The problem is running the first function then the second. Thank you for the help.

```
-(void)timere:(UITextField*)f1 {

    UITextField*fielder1=f1;
    NSInvocation*timerInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(moveP:)]];


    [timerInvocation setSelector:@selector(moveP:)];
    [timerInvocation setTarget:self];
    [timerInvocation setArgument:&fielder1 atIndex:2];   

    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 invocation:timerInvocation repeats:YES];
}


-(void) moveP:(UITextField*)f1 {

    UITextField*fielder1=f1;
    fielder1.center = CGPointMake(fielder1.center.x+4, fielder1.center.y);
    if (fielder1.center.x>237) {
        [timer1 invalidate];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standardized method of animating UIView objects is by using methods such as the following.

[+ animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

The syntax for these methods might be a bit daunting if you are unfamiliar with [Objective-C Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Here's a usage example which moves the first field, then the second field afterwards.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
  [field1 setCenter:CGPointMake(FINAL_CENTER_X1, FINAL_CENTER_Y1)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [field2 setCenter:CGPointMake(FINAL_CENTER_X2, FINAL_CENTER_Y2)];
  }];
}];
```

EDIT: For a general fix on your specific problem, I would make the following modifications:

```
-(IBAction)changeX {
    [self timere:field1];
}

-(void) moveP:(UITextField*)f1 {

    UITextField*fielder1=f1;
    fielder1.center = CGPointMake(fielder1.center.x+4, fielder1.center.y);
    if (fielder1.center.x>237) {
        [timer1 invalidate];
        // I'm really not sure about the scope of field1 and field2, but
        // you can figure out the encapsulation issues
        if (f1 == field1) {
            [self timere:field2];
        }
    }

}
```

A more generic and indeed low-level solution would be to have a state variable. Perhaps you would have some sort of `NSArray *fields` of `UITextField *` and `int state = 0`. Where I added the conditional in `moveP` above, you would `state++` and call `[self timere:[fields objectAtIndex:state]]` if `state < [fields count]`. You timer invalidation code is correct, anyway.

Comment: im using uitextfield objects though and even then both functions inside the function changeX will still run. im looking for a way to do this successively instead of both functions running at the same time. Is there a general way to stop one function from running until another completes.

Comment: This answer will animate `field1`, and then animate `field2` after `field1`'s animation is complete.  It starts the animation of `field2` from the completion block of `field1`'s animation.

Comment: this would help alot for these type of objects but want to know a method of solving this in general. for example if i had this instead

Comment: [self firstTimer:field1 :field2];
 
 [field1 setText:@"field1 text"]; this would run the first method still and im asuming in other cases it doesn't stop until the method is done to begin another one. is there a way around this for any method in general. to just tell the second method to wait for the first to finish. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you want a general solution then you were certainly on the right track. Let me edit my solution to accommodate.

Comment: my problem isn't just with the first two fields. what i'm trying to do is have these two methods in the same function(the timere function i had on the first post). What i need is a way in general of being able to run the first method then the second method. I've been doing some reading around the site and came across many posts describing how the ui for the iphone is supposedly asynchronous and return callbacks when complete. i want a way to be able to run it synchronously. But everything ive read online involves multithreading( NSLock , NSOperationQueue , GCD etc)

Comment: So basically you want the program to hang on the first part until the corresponding timer is invalidated, then to move on to the second part? I suppose you could standardize the process by creating a class that has a timer and accepts an execution code block and a completion code block. The class would have an object method `- [SyncBlock invalidate]` which would invalidate its local timer and execute the completion code block. There are many different ways to encapsulate this idea.

Comment: i actually meant the method -(IBAction)changeX {
    [self timere:field1];
    [self timere:field2];
}
is there not anyway around code blocks because i know absolutely nothing on that. what would i have to learn in order to make my method sequential. I guess ill have to put this little app on halt. Would code blocks solve my problem though?

Comment: Code blocks are essentially just dynamic function pointers (anonymous functions) that are passed to a method for future use. Anyway, you don't have to use code blocks at all. You could implement my aforementioned class using the [id/selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) protocol. You could go the even more complicated route and use `NSInvocation`, but that is not so intuitive and gets extremely messy.

Comment: i solved the problem with [self performSelector:@selector(method:) withObject: theObject afterDelay:certainTime]; using a for loop. However , the program in its entirety finishes extremely fast but the delay is what allows me to move the objects one at a time(inside the loop the delaytime continously increments). Also theObject is just the two fields put inside a wrapper with nsmutablearray so the selector can take multiple methods. Thanks for all the help.